# As3: Access public variable from movie clips class? (Both from timeline and within a class)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables, public, var

I have a public variable on an enemy class.

How do I access this variable in the, let's say, main class? Or hero class? Or any class?

I know you can access main class variables with _root. (after it is defined), but how do I access external class values?

ALSO:

How can I access these external class values from the TIMELINE on a specific movieclip?

Here is the code:

In Worker.as, I have

```
This part of code is part of a continuous ENTER_FRAME loop..



        if(isFlying)
        {
            if(!faceLeft)
            {
                gotoAndStop(8);
            }
            if(faceLeft)
            {
                gotoAndStop(7);
            }

            if(flyingDestination < this.x)
            {
                if(this.x > flyingDestination)
                {
                    this.x -= 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    isFlying = false;
                    _root.mainIsFlying = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(this.x < flyingDestination)
                {
                    this.x += 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    isFlying = false;
                    _root.mainIsFlying = false;
                }
            }
        }

if(_root.isPunching)
        {
            if(this.hitTestObject(_root.ceo))
               {
                   isFlying = true;

                   if(this.x < _root.ceo.x)
                   {
                        flyToTheLeft();
                   }
                   if(this.x > _root.ceo.x)
                   {
                        flyToTheRight();
                   }

               }
        }


And these are separate functions, a.k.a not part of the ENTER_FRAME function.

private function flyToTheLeft():void
{
    flyingDestination = this.x - 100;
    faceLeft = true;
}

private function flyToTheRight():void
{
    flyingDestination = this.x + 100;
}
```

On frame 8 of the worker movieclip lies the flying animation. In this flying animation, I want, on the last frame of this flying animation, the code to say something like:

```
stop();
WORKER.as.isFlying = false;
```

^^^^^
I don't know how to code that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understand your problem, could you pass a little of code?
Small hint, you should use private variables as a good OOP practice and getter/setter methods. Here you can find how to do that:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-inheritance-setters-getters-basix--active-6104

Answer (score 0):

If the isFlying variable is defined in WORKER.as, and you want to change the variable for all instances you should define the variable as `public static var isFlying = false` and can then change it like this `WORKER.isFlying = false` without the .as extension.
If you want the variable changed per instance `this.parent.isFlying = false` should work.